# save 3d graph to multiple format

Tags: r

I currently have a 3d graph  and I would like to save the output in both png and pdf. Is there a way to save it in those format at the same time? I know there is a ggplot function that can save plot but I'm not sure how in base r.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know you will need at least 2 lines of code, if this is what you mean. I like to use the `dev.print()` function to save graphics. The function is saving a copy of the plot your are currently looking at. Please note that dev.print() copy the interactive window and not directly the plot as it is specified in the help section.

## dev.print() example:

```
dev.print(png, "yourfile.png")
dev.print(pdf, "yourfile.pdf")
```

To know where your file is saved you can also get and set your working directory with those 2 functions :
`getwd()` and `setwd()`

You can also use the `png()` and `pdf()` functions to save plot specifically in those format.

Your question is probably a duplicate tho.